# How to make the function both accept parameters in the pipeline and use all-position parameters?

Tags: powershell

There is a function `add` to enable it to receive both parameters and positions through the pipeline.

The specific effect is as follows:

`'A' | add 'B' | Should -Be 'AB'`

`add 'A' 'B' | Should -Be 'AB'`

Having tried all three options, there is no way to achieve the above assertion at the same time.

So how exactly should we achieve this effect?

```
# case 0
function add {
    [CmdletBinding()]
    param (
        [Parameter(Mandatory, ValueFromPipeline)]
        [String[]]
        $a,
        [Parameter(Position = 1)]
        [String[]]
        $b = 'C'
    )
    process {
        "$a$b"
    }
}
```

```
# case 1
function add {
    [CmdletBinding()]
    param (
        [Parameter(Mandatory, ValueFromPipeline,Position = 1)]
        [String[]]
        $a,
        [Parameter(Position = 2)]
        [String[]]
        $b = 'C'
    )
    process {
        "$a$b"
    }
}
```

```
# case 2
function add {
    [CmdletBinding()]
    param (
        [Parameter(Mandatory, ValueFromPipeline,ParameterSetName = "pipe")]
        [Parameter(Mandatory, ValueFromPipeline,Position = 1,ParameterSetName = "Param")]
        [String[]]
        $a,
        [Parameter(Position = 1,ParameterSetName = "pipe")]
        [Parameter(Mandatory, ValueFromPipeline,Position = 2,ParameterSetName = "Param")]
        [String[]]
        $b = 'C'
    )
    process {
        "$a$b"
    }
}
```

Comment: what are you asking for? Are you just trying to accept the input from the Pipeline and concatenate it to your default `$b` variable?

Comment: @AbrahamZinala No, this is just an example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the requirement was `add 'B' 'A'` then it would be very simple.

The pipe parameter should be placed at the end of the parameter list, because when the parameter is entered through the pipe, the corresponding position is not available, then all the later position parameters will be wrong, but if it is at the end, then its presence or absence will not affect the other parameters.

`add 'B' 'A'` looks a bit strange simply because the two parameter positions are in a different order than they are in the alphabet.

```
function add {
    [CmdletBinding()]
    param (
        [Parameter(Mandatory)]
        $b,
        [Parameter(ValueFromPipeline, Mandatory)]
        $a
    )
    process {
        "$a$b"
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what you're trying to achieve but, it works for me:

```
function add {
    [CmdletBinding()]
    param (
        [Parameter(Mandatory, ValueFromPipeline, Position = 0)]
        [String]$a,
        [Parameter(Mandatory, ValueFromPipeline, Position = 1)]
        [String]$b
    )
    process {
        "$a$b"
    }
}
```

Test examples:

```
PS /~> 'A' | add -b 'B' ; add 'A' 'B' ; add -b 'B' -a 'A' ; 'B' | add -a 'A'

AB
AB
AB
AB
```